# Find PyWin32 method similar to the xlwings packages

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, xlwings, vba

Currently I am using xlwings to open my Excel workbook and I am able to catch the data in a specific cells by using "find" method. However, xlwings is taking to much time to open the Excel, I want to replace xlwings package with PyWin32 package the will be used for my development.

But I cannot find same method like xlwings. Is there any method to catch data in the Excel like xlwings that can be implemented in PyWin32.

Appreciate your help.

Below is example of code in xlwings:

```
find_location = wbook.api.Cells.Find(What='car',
                          LookAt=xlwings.constants.LookAt.xlWhole
                          LookIn=xlwings.constants.FindLookIn.xlFormulas,
                          SearchOrder=xlwings.constants.SearchOrder.xlByColumns,
                          SerchDirection=xlwings.constants.SearchDirection.xlNext,
                          MatchCase = False)
```

Comment: *pywin32* is a wrapper over *WINAPI*s. *WINAPI*s allow working with *Excel* via *COM*, which offers a very generic interface. In order to achieve your goal, you'll gave to duplicate (quite some) functionality from *xlwings*.

Answer (score 0):

I got here as first hit looking for pywin32 lookat xlwhole. So I have not tested all parts of above query. But I did test "LookAt", and reading Excel Range.Find method from Microsoft, I believe the chance of all parts working is good.

What, LookAt, LookIn, Searchorder, SearchDirection and MatchCase are all part of Microsoft standard Range.Find call parameters (thus also part of Cells.Find). What Pywin32 seem to be missing, are the constants only.

From Microsoft documentation, declaring "LookAt=1" gives same result as "LookAt=xlwings.constants.LookAt.xlWhole".

Such a find runs fine using pywin32.